# Javascript: Remove Value from array inside an array of Object based on key

Tags: javascript, arrays, filter

I have an array like this .

```
{
  "filters": [
   
    {
      "filterProperty": "companyType",
      "filterValues": [
        "Private"
      ]
    },
    {
      "filterProperty": "city",
      "filterValues": [
        "Mumbai",
        "SanJose",
        "Shanghai"
      ]
    }
    
  ]
}
```

I have applied Filters. now I am removing them One by One and calling an API with remaining Filters.

so when I pass filterProperty as "city" and value as "Mumbai" then only "Mumbai" would remove from filterProperty "city" . the rest filter values should be same.

How can I do so ?

```js
  "filters": [
   
    {
      "filterProperty": "companyType",
      "filterValues": [
        "Private"
      ]
    },
    {
      "filterProperty": "city",
      "filterValues": [
        "Mumbai",
        "SanJose",
        "Shanghai"
      ]
    }
    
  ]


let data = filters.splice(a=> a.filterProperty === 'city' && a.filterValues.filter(a => a == "Mumbai"))
```

Comment: The [`splice`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice) method does not take a function...

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I remove a specific item from an array?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5767325/how-can-i-remove-a-specific-item-from-an-array)

Comment: that doesn't solve my answer. thank you

Comment: Sure it does. `const filter = filters.find(f => f.filterProperty === 'city'); filter.filterValues.splice(filter.filterValues.indexOf('Mumbai'), 1);`

Answer (score 0):

I assume you need `map` along with `filter`. Something like this:

```js
const obj = { "filters": [ { "filterProperty": "companyType", "filterValues": [ "Private" ] }, { "filterProperty": "city", "filterValues": [ "Mumbai", "SanJose", "Shanghai" ] } ]};

const result = obj.filters.map(k=>(k.filterProperty == "city" ? (k.filterValues = k.filterValues.filter(o=>o!=='Mumbai'), k) : k ));

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `Array.reduce()`

```js
let filters=[{filterProperty:"companyType",filterValues:["Private"]},{filterProperty:"city",filterValues:["Mumbai","SanJose","Shanghai"]}];

let data = filters.reduce((acc,cur) => {
  if(cur.filterProperty === "city"){
    cur.filterValues.splice(cur.filterValues.indexOf("Mumbai"),1)
  }
  acc.push(cur)
  return acc
},[])

console.log(data)
```

Answer (score 0):

Without `mutating the data`, use `forEach` and `filter` build new array of items.

```js
const filter = (obj, prop, value) => {
  const filters = [];
  obj.filters.forEach(({ filterProperty, filterValues }) => {
    filters.push({
      filterProperty,
      filterValues: filterValues.filter((item) =>
        filterProperty === prop ? item != value : true
      ),
    });
  });
  return {
    filters,
  };
};

const data = {
  filters: [
    {
      filterProperty: "companyType",
      filterValues: ["Private"],
    },
    {
      filterProperty: "city",
      filterValues: ["Mumbai", "SanJose", "Shanghai"],
    },
  ],
};

const prop = "city";
const value = "Mumbai";

console.log(filter(data, prop, value));
```

Solution with `mutating the data`, using `find` and `splice`

```js
const data = {
  filters: [
    {
      filterProperty: "companyType",
      filterValues: ["Private"],
    },
    {
      filterProperty: "city",
      filterValues: ["Mumbai", "SanJose", "Shanghai"],
    },
  ],
};

const prop = "city";
const value = "Mumbai";

const city = data.filters.find(({ filterProperty }) => filterProperty === prop);
if (city) {
  const index = city.filterValues.findIndex((item) => item === value);
  if (index > -1) {
    city.filterValues.splice(index, 1);
  }
}

console.log(data);
```